# Node.js Multer ".array is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I've been looking and trying to figure this out for two days now, and the only real mention of it that I can find is an old issue report on version 1.1.0 which was closed without resolution: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/338

I'm using Node.js SDK and Express framework, with Cloudinary as my image host.

This is just a project for a class, but it's important that I know how to get this to work for future projects.

```
const multer = require('multer');
//configure where/how files are stored temporarily
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    filename: function(req,file,cb) {
        cv(null,Date.now() + file.originalname);
    },
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/uploads')
      }
});
//only accept image files for cloudinary
const imageFilter = (req,file,cb) => {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)) {
        return cb(new Error('Only image files (jpg, jpeg, png, gif) are allowed!'), false);
    }
    else {
        cb(null,true);
    }
};
//configure multer's upload parameters
const upload = multer({storage:storage, filefilter:imageFilter}).array('image',5);

/* POST new post  */
router.post('/', upload.array('image', 5) ,asyncErrorHandler(postCreate));
```

console error when trying to run Node: `TypeError: upload.array is not a function`

I'm handling the actual logic of using the files in what is supposed to be the "files" array, but it won't even get that far, it just stops at `upload.array()` when trying to compile the file.

Below are the dependencies from my package.json just in case any other modules are known to interfere:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^3.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.18.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-sanitizer": "^1.0.5",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "locus": "^2.0.4",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.5",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^6.0.1",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found my problem:

I was calling the `array()` method both when creating the `upload` constant as well as in the middleware when calling that constant for the route. Removed it from the constant declaration and all is well.